# How can I handle selected value from button click?

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, dropdown

I have a `dropdown`, When I click on items, the selected Item value shows on the dropdown and it's good but I want to clear the `dropdown` when the user clicks on a button. I use `setState` but it doesn't work correctly.
This is my code:

This is my DorpdownCmp that I've customized it

> 

```
export default function DropdownCmp(someProps...) {

 return (
       <Select
          onClick={onClick}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          error={error}
          value={value}
          color="success"
          onSelect={onSelect}
          onChange={onChange}
          input={<OutlinedInput name={name} id={name} label={label} />}
         
        >
        </select>
);
}
```

MainComponent:

> 

```
  const [selectedItemVal, setSelectedItemVal] = useState<any>();
   const test = (e: any) => {
  if (e == undefined) {
    setSelectedItemVal(undefined);
  } else {
    setSelectedItemVal(e.target.value);
  }
 }
  return (
  <Grid item xs={8}>
            <DropdownCmp
              onChange={test}
              value={selectedItemVal || undefined}
              label={" نوع درآمد"}
              options={dataType.data}
              name="id"
              id="id"
            />
        <Button
          onClick={() => setSelectedItemVal(undefined)}
        >test</Button>
  )
```